# Форма поиска пропадает при уменьшении широты экрана

Tags: javascript

В js новичок, углубляться в язык не буду, так что с этим туго.

Такое дело, есть форма поиска на сайте https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCZ6F.jpg, которую при максимальной ширине экрана 1199px убираю и вместо него ставлю кнопку мобильного поиска, при нажатии на которую появляется форма поиска https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIrjJ.jpg.

А проблема состоит в том, что после повторного нажатия на кнопку поиска когда пропадает форма, при уменьшении ширины экрана пропадает кнопка мобильного поиска, но форма не появляется https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn9hr.jpg.

Вот js код:

```
let mobileSearch = document.getElementById('mobile-search');
let searchForm = document.getElementById('search-form');
let headerInput = document.getElementById('header__input');
let bannerBackground = document.getElementById('banner-background');
    
mobileSearch.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(searchForm.style.display == 'block') {
        searchForm.style.display = 'none';
        bannerBackground.classList.remove('banner-before');
    }
    else {
        searchForm.style.display = 'block';
        bannerBackground.classList.add('banner-before');
        headerInput.focus();
    }
});
```

И вот также как я "пытался" решить эту проблему:

```
let mobileSearch = document.getElementById('mobile-search');
let searchForm = document.getElementById('search-form');
let headerInput = document.getElementById('header__input');
let bannerBackground = document.getElementById('banner-background');
let x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1199px)");

function myMediaQuery(x) {
    if (x.matches) {
        mobileSearch.addEventListener("click", function() {
            if(searchForm.style.display == 'block') {
                searchForm.style.display = 'none';
                bannerBackground.classList.remove('banner-before');
            }
            else {
                searchForm.style.display = 'block';
                bannerBackground.classList.add('banner-before');
                headerInput.focus();
            }
        });
    }
}
    
x.addListener(myMediaQuery);
```

Всем ответившим заранее спасибо.

Comment: А не пробовали решить это без JS, а на CSS с помощью медиа запросов?

Comment: Было бы круто, но дело в том, что панель поиска я показываю изначально, при достижении 1199px я его скрываю и меняю ему стили, а вместо него ставлю другую кнопку поиска, при нажатии на которую и должна появляться форма поиска с измененными стилями. И насколько я знаю(могу ошибаться) этого не сделаешь на css.

Comment: Вот быстро накидал чтоб показать суть: https://codepen.io/Lukyanenko/pen/XWdeeyb
Если поменяете размер экрана, то поменяется верстка. Или я не правильно понимаю задачу?

Comment: Верстку я меняю, но нужно показывать форму поиска по нажатию на мобильную версию иконки поиска, а это как я понял нельзя на css

Comment: Вот попытался еще это исправить https://pastebin.com/FLUDSC6A, но в браузере смотрю для формы поиска стоит display: none

Comment: https://codepen.io/Lukyanenko/pen/XWdeeyb?editors=1111 - вам типа такого что то нужно ?

Comment: Я попробовал так, как вы сказали, но снова при уменьшении ширины экрана форма поиска пропадает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге все решилось, двумя функциями:

```
function showForm(){ if(x.matches) searchForm.style.display = 'block' }
function hideForm(){ if(f.matches) searchForm.style.display = 'none' }

let x = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1199px)");
showForm();
x.addListener(showForm);

let f = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1199px)");
hideForm();
f.addListener(hideForm);
```